# mysql regexp some of these chars + 1 unknown char

Tags: mysql, regex, string

This regexp bellow means that word must be only of (some) letters of ABC. so A matches, AA, AB, BA

```
word REGEXP '^[ABC]*$'
```

but how to make it some of ABC letters and **one** any uknown letter.

Comment: It could also match an empty string as the * means 0 or more times. `^[ABC]+[a-zA-Z]$` would match 1+ times either A B or C and then a char a-z or A-Z.

Comment: @Thefourthbird not at the end but anywhere in the word

Comment: @luky Then, `^[ABC]+[A-Za-z]?[ABC]*$`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ztAlQW/1

Comment: @41686d6564 well done, you probably nailed it. this could work it seems ^[ABC]*[A-Z]?[ABC]*$

Comment: @luky Yes, but that will work even if no `[ABC]` present in the string at all. It will also match an empty string (because everything is optional now). So, it's up to you to decide what characters to make optional.

Comment: @41686d6564 you are right. there is actually also length condition so that is no trouble. but thanks, because i would not be able to put it together myself it seems.

Comment: @41686d6564 and how would you make 2 any chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a string with just `A`, `B`, `C` letters and one any letter, you can use

```
REGEXP '^[ABC]*([A-Z][ABC]*)?$'
```

To match a similar string of `A`, `B` and `C` with any *two* letters, you can use

```
REGEXP '^[ABC]*([A-Z][ABC]*){0,2}$'
```

since `?` is basically `{0,1}` quanitifier. See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/lqQbsU/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/lqQbsU/2).

**NOTE**: If you do not want the additional letters to be `A`, `B` or `C`, replace `[A-Z]` with `[D-Z]`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[ABC]*` - zero or more `A`, `B` or `C` chars
- `([A-Z][ABC]*)?` - an optional (one or zero, if `{0,2}` is used, then zero, one or two) occurrence of any ASCII letter followed with zero or more `A`, `B` or `C` chars
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 0):

Requiring *one* letter other than ABC:

```
x REGEXP '^[ABC]*[D-Z][ABC]*$'
```

*Allowing* *one* letter other than ABC:

```
x REGEXP '^[ABC]*[D-Z]?[ABC]*$'
```

Length restriction:

```
... AND CHAR_LENGTH(x) > 3
... AND CHAR_LENGTH(x) BETWEEN 2 AND 5
(etc)
```

Comment: This case is already covered in Wiktor's answer, see "NOTE: If you do not want the additional letters to be `A`, `B` or `C`, replace `[A-Z]` with `[D-Z]`."